# Play multiple HTML videos without interrupts

Tags: javascript, html, optimization, html5-video

So the context is I heard that a big part of YouTube's algorithm for video optimisation is to split videos into three second chunks so that users only load the sections of the video they watch, which makes a lot of sense.

And so what I managed to do with ffmpeg is exactly that, to cut a video into three second chunks. The dilemna I'm faced with is I'm storing each one of these 51 three second chunks of an mp4 file on an Amazon Backblaze B2 bucket and each of them have a different link.

I was just wondering if it would be possible to somehow play all of them in a smooth way one from the other like it's a single video with some JQuery, HTML or otherwise and only load the segments that a user watches.

I am also aware of the Mediasource api from a similar question here: https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2011/11/Stream-video-using-the-MediaSource-API

However, that seems to take an entire video and then 'streams' it to a video tag which I guess works, but it only works with Google Chrome which is a big disadvantage.

What my code currently looks like is this, but this would only be one three second part.

```html
    <video width="1920" height="1080" controls>
     <source src="https://f002.backblazeb2.com/b2api/v1/b2_download_file_by_id?fileId=4_z4f7a200716_f106f809ac97cfcd3_d20200521_m032927_c002_v0001133_t0038" type="video/mp4">
     Your browser does not support the video tag.
   </video>
```

Comment: they use a fragmented mpeg format (eg DASH or HLS) which most modern browser have native support for. While technically they are just n second chunks they also have a manifest to tell the browser what's happening next. If you have a single bitrate file with the MOOV atom at the start and your server supports byte range requests you'll also see efficiencies as it will only download the parts it needs

Comment: @Offbeatmammal thanks I have heard that they were in hls format and I know I can convert to HLS with ffmpeg. Just a question if I have converted the entire mp4 video into hls with ffmpeg would it just be a matter of using this hls video as part of the src attribute inside an html video tag?